# How to text message send using timing in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I send the message from android by using below code but my question was when type some message on Edit text to be stop typing on edit text start timing after 30seconds automatically send message to others how to do this help me how to get time give idea

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    String phone = intent.getStringExtra("pho");
                    String fullmsg = sendText.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("messga body full test", "" + fullmsg);

                    try {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phone, null, fullmsg,
                                null, null);
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put("address", phone);
                        values.put("body", fullmsg);
                        getContentResolver().insert(
                                Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "SMS faild, please try again.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Make your Edittext disable after 30 sec and get what ever text in edittxt and send it.

Comment: when you want to stop typing ??

Comment: when i type before 30 seconds to restart the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use java Timers, use Handlers (Timer have an own thread will must not operate with UI elements). Each View has a handler call for delayed operations:

```
View v=..... (or inherided call)
v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      // your code
    }
}, 30*1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String number = "";
        String message_text = "";

        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message_text, null, null);         
    }

}, 30000);
```

Comment: There is no need for a new Handler, each View has one.